# Powershell: Encapsulate numbers in quotes if not already encapsulated

Tags: regex

The system i'm working on stores SSNs in a database using varchar(10), I am not allowed to change that.
I have an automated script that runs, reading a submitted ticket, and using the query in the ticket, carries out the required task. Frequently we have queries being submitted with SSNs not in quotations, when stored as varchar this fails.
I want to have a regex that checks the query for any SSNs and if not encapsulated, does so with single quotations.
I'd been trying to use this but it's replacing the first and last characters in each numeric string. so 123456789 results in '2345678'.
Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$String = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table WHERE ssn in (123456786,876543217,'321654784',345676873)"
$String -replace "(?<!'|\d)\d","'" -replace "\d(?!'|\d)","'"
```

Results in

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table WHERE ssn in ('2345678','7654321','321654784','4567687')
```

Comment: Did it finally work? Do you think it needs any adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

Use lookarounds to avoid consuming the digits:

```
$String -replace "(?<!['\d])\d+(?!['\d])", "'`$&'"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3YBwqs/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!['\d])` - a location that is not immediately preceded with a digit or single quote
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?!['\d])` - a location that is not immediately followed with a digit or single quote.

The `` "'`$&'" `` replacement replaced with the whole match (`$&`) enclosed with single quotes.

[image]